# Add meteorite package error

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have a problem installing packages in Meteor. I have used to sudo installation for Meteorite and i still get the "problem when cloning repo" error. I have reinstalled/unistalled both Meteor and Meteorite several times.

This is the error I get in the terminal:

ERROR: null Command failed:

STDOUT:

STDERR:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
                                                              ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/BenjaminRH/meteor-event-hooks.git
Please check https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting for potential explanations.

I've tried to follow suggestions from other posts without any luck.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Go to your home directory and check who is the owner of `.meteorite`, `.meteor` and `.npm` (and maybe `tmp`) directories. If it is `root`, chage it (recursivelly) to yourself and see what will happen.

Comment: @apendua: I don't quite understand what you mean here, I should say I'm on a mac though. I'm the only user, if I got your answer correctly(?)
thanks

Comment: If you're on a UNIX system (like Mac OS for example), there is always the `root` user. If you `sudo` something you act as if you were the `root` user, so if you install anything with `sudo` prefix the instalation process may create directories (even within your own `home`) that are owned by `root`. This may cause problems with priviliges. So please verify, e.g. by looking at the output of `ls -la` what is the owner of the directories I listed for you in the previous comment.

Comment: @apendua I'm sorry but how do I do that exactly, via the terminal? I'm not sure what that means really, if I run ls -la in the terminal I get a list of folders basically, all with me as "staff" Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeap, you need to run the command in terminal in your home dir. If all the folders are owned by you and the `staff` group, then everything seems correct. To make sure that also all subdirectories has the correct privileges, call `chmod [username]:staff -R .meteor .meteorite .npm`. You can also try removing the `.meteorite` directory and try to reinstall your smart packages, so `mrt install` in your project directory.

Comment: When removing the .meteorite folder and run mrt install in the app directory I get the same error "There was a problem cloning repo:"
Tried to run the chmod command which said chmod: "Invalid file mode:" (I replaced [username] with my name basically) and tried both with and without the brackets and without :staff too just in case.

Comment: Did I write `chmod`? Sorry for that... what I meant was `chown`.

Comment: Ok, it says "No such file or directory".

Comment: sorry it says " -R no such file or directory"